# How can I replace a soundcloud url to an iFrame (PHP)

Tags: php, url, iframe, preg-replace

How can I detect and replace a soundcloud url in a text with an iframe using PHP:

For example:

This:

```
https://soundcloud.com/s/eminem-ft-dr-dre-old-time-sake
```

Into this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/140068709&amp;color=00aabb&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function linkifySoundcloudURLs( $text )
  {
    $text = preg_replace('#https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*soundcloud\.com\/([^< ]+)#ix',
    '<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/$1&amp;color=00aabb&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>',
      $text);
    return $text;
  }
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but something like this?

```
<?php
  $url = "https://soundcloud.com/aathmigan/eminem-ft-dr-dre-old-time-sake";
?>    

<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"
    src="<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would like to use `preg_replace`. Why not set a url-variable using `if`, `else if` and `else` instead? Help me understand, explain what it is for and how it should be used.

Comment: I need a function with preg replace because it should first detect the link in the text and then replace the link

Comment: If-else would be much easier, but if you really need `preg_replace`, use [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#Hcom89364).

Comment: [This link](http://www.regexr.com/) is great if you want to play with regular expressions.